# Images from drawable or blob

Tags: android, sqlite, apk

In my app there is a SQLite database no need to modify/update database. I am bringing only some data from database & each data is associated with a photo

My app consists of 200 photos. The solutions possible are

1. These 200 photos can be used from drawable folder directly
2. Otherwise I can add a column as blob & retrieve these 200 photos from SQLite.

Which method will lead me to small apk size ?

Comment: What difference did you measure?

Comment: I dont know what is the difference between these 2 methods, or which is better

Comment: I think you have to pull images after app installed from server if your concern is on APK size or use some library which cache images on sdcard. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the URL for images on SQLite database as **TEXT**, and use image libraries to retrieve them

This libraries :

**[picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**

**[Volley image loader](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/volley-part-3-image-loader)**

For example on Picasso :
assume that you saved the URLs for images on SQLite , and then you retrieved them on ArrayList , one on them was https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg").into(mImageView);
```

Comment: Picasso is simple and good library for loading images. And performs best if you used it with okHttp. here is the example of OkHttp-2.0.0-RC1, otto-1.3.4 and picasso-2.3.1 https://github.com/AnawazInc/OkHttp-Picasso-Example-Android

Comment: how can I get this type of link as my image?

Comment: more details @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw please :D